# y-position not correct at adding a UIView to another UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview, uidatepicker

I've added two `UIViews` to a view with the following code. `self.view` is my view in the navigation controller.

```
CGRect rect = [self.view bounds];
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 
                                       self.datePicker.frame.size.height - 44,
                                self.datePicker.frame.size.width,
                                self.datePicker.frame.size.height);
CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tView.frame.size.width, 
                               self.view.frame.size.height - 
                                   self.datePicker.frame.size.height);
[self.datePicker setFrame:pickerFrame];
[self.tView setFrame:tableFrame];

[self.view addSubview:self.tView];
[self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];
```

I expected, that the picker was below the `tableView`, but that was not the result. The result was a 44 pixel width bar between the two objects. What is the reason? I don't understand this issue.

Comment: Have you tried logging/debugging the frames, seems like issue with the frame as you are referencing frame of several views. As A view's Frame: the position and size of a viewinside the superview where the view will fill.

A view's Bound: the position and size of a view inside the view itself.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add picker below the tableview then first set the frame of tableview first and then set the Y position of picker accordingly. Suppose this is your iPhone application and you want to add a table and then a pickerview then your code will be like this -

```
CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tView.frame.size.width, (self.view.frame.size.height - self.datePicker.frame.size.height));

[self.tView setFrame:tableFrame];
```

and then set the frame of pickerview like -

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.tView.frame.size.height+2, self.datePicker.frame.size.width, self.datePicker.frame.size.height);
[self.datePicker setFrame:pickerFrame];
```

and then add these object to your view

```
[self.view addSubview:self.tView];
[self.view addSubview:self.datePicker];
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The picker cant be under your tableView because the tableView uses

```
self.view.frame.size.height - self.datePicker.frame.size.height
```

as hight
while the y position of you pickerview is smaller

```
self.view.frame.size.height - self.datePicker.frame.size.height -44
```

Answer (score 0):

`(0, 0)` is top left, not bottom left.
When you say `-44` you are specifying a point `44` pixels above.

Let's say `self.view` is `150` pixels high and `self.datePicker` is `50` pixels high.

When you say:

```
CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height - 
                                       self.datePicker.frame.size.height - 44,
                                self.datePicker.frame.size.width,
                                self.datePicker.frame.size.height);
```

`pickerFrame.origin.y` is `150 - 50 - 44 = 56`

When you say:

```
CGRect tableFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tView.frame.size.width,
                               self.view.frame.size.height - 
                                   self.datePicker.frame.size.height);
```

`tableFrame.size.height` is `150 - 50 = 100`

`56` is lower than `100` so the picker is higher up than the table